# NLP. Which tool can I use to distinguish between function and content words?

Tags: nlp

I need distinguish between functional and content words. I used Tint as a tool and Stanford NLP but I didn't handle it. Could help me with that please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You simply need a POS tagger, there is certainly one in Stanford NLP. Once you obtain the POS for the words in the text, the content words are the ones corresponding to noun, verbs and adverbs categories (any other category is a functional word). To make this even more precise, you can use a stop words list and consider words in this list as functional too.